# List и метод append к переменной в Python

Tags: python, append, round

Делаю в функции list.append(var).
var это округленная позиционная переменная первого списка.
Однако в последствии получаю не измененный список (е) с значениями первого списка(х).

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    t = round(x[i], -2)
    # e.append(round(x[i], -2))
    e.append(t)
    print("x", x[i], "t", t, "round xi", round(x[i], -2))

print("x", x)
print(round(x[0], -2), round(x[1], -2), round(x[2], -2), round(x[4], -2))
print("e", x)
```

результат

```
x 0 t 0 round xi 0
x 123 t 100 round xi 100
x 246 t 200 round xi 200
...
x 12054 t 12100 round xi 12100
x 12177 t 12200 round xi 12200
x [0, 123, 246, 369, ... , 12054, 12177]
0 100 200 500
e [0, 123, 246, 369, ... , 12054, 12177]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

подскажите в чем особенность, что не так делаю

Comment: Вы написали про функцию, но в вашем вопросе нет никакой функции.

Comment: Вы в конце два раза выводите список x - print("x", x) и print("e", x). В цикле меняете список e.
Как мы должны из этого что-то понять? Может вы банально вместо е x написали случайно?

Comment: Спасибо. @Alpensin

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in x:
    t = round(i, -2)
    # e.append(round(x[i], -2))
    e.append(t)
    print("x",i , "t", t, "round xi", round(i, -2))

print("x", x)
print(round(x[0], -2), round(x[1], -2), round(x[2], -2), round(x[4], -2))
print("e", x)
```

если правильно понял - мне кажется, здесь лишнее range, со всеми вытекающими

Comment: Вся соль, как подсказал Alpensin в print в котором я пишу название "е", а список запрашиваю на вывод 'х' ...очепятка которая ввела в ступор